# Is there a way to restrict actions to specified number of iterations?

Tags: loadrunner

Let say I have 4 actions in  my script. I want first 3 actions will repeat for 5 iterations and 4 all actions will run for 8 iterations in VU Gen. 
I am using load runner 11.52 version.
is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Un-schedule inside of run time settings.  Then use the Action() as a driver to call your own actions

```
Action()
{
     int outside_counter, inside_counter++
     for ( outside_counter=1; outside_counter<=8;outside_counter++)
     {
          custom_action1();
          for (inside_counter=1;inside_counter<=4;inside_counter++)
          {
               action2();
               action3();
               action4();
               action5();
          }
     }
return 0;
}
```

Or, you can do this with custom groups in the run time scheduler.  I prefer by hand so I can see and control exactly what is happening.